# Subtract time from duration only if above specified amount

Tags: excel, function, if-statement, xls, equation

Working on a timesheet (duplicate of sheet 1 in [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bK4Vtzh2e55AEnOtdCciYRhLkcfr8Ns65q-nXyKah28/edit?usp=sharing)). 
The current function to handle the calculations is:

B4=6:00am
C4=6:00pm
X4=0:30:00

```
=IF(OR(B4="",C4=""),"",IFERROR(C4-B4-X4,""))
```

The thing is we don't subtract 30 minutes for lunch unless an employee works longer than 6 hours and 15 minutes.

How can I fix my function to only subtract 30 mins for lunch if the total time for that day is over 6 hours and 15 mins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided there is no risk of times spanning midnight, please try:

```
=IF(OR(B4="",C4=""),"",IF(C4-B4>6.25/24,C4-B4-X4,C4-B4))
```

Comment: So far, this works.  Ill keep testing.  There will be no times that span midnight.  Thanks!

Comment: I dont use excel that often, what exactly do you mean?  Right now I just have X4 as a hidden column that everything pulls from.